# How to document a function that takes a callback?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm writing an asynchronous library and some of my method take callbacks as parameters:

```
/// \brief Opens a connection to the remote server defined by the parameters passed in the constructor.
/// \param[in] callback Callback passed when the connection is estabelished or fails.
/// \return Any errors encountered by the library or the OS.
virtual connect(std::function<void(std::error_code ec)> callback) noexcept = 0;
```

How can document the callback's parameters in Doxygen?

Comment: Doesn't doxygen take that?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: I don't understand your question either. What does doxygen output for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a way to document the functor itself in a nested fashion (function within a function param), but Doxygen doesn't suppor that AFAIK. You could do it manually with [`\parblock`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparblock) and some [Doxygen Markdown](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html). Another manual way would be to move the callback definition to a `typedef` and document it there with [`\typedef`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtypedef), which would again require manual effort since Doxygen doesn't support functors in this way.